# Comparing survival rates

Tags: survival, proportion, paired-data

The question I have is focused on comparing remission rates at a fixed point in time.
For example, I have cancer type A and cancer type B (the two are not mutually exclusive groups) and all patients underwent treatment X. What I hope to do is only to compare the rate of remission (not precisely survival) for those with cancer type A and type B.

Say 30% of those with type A has lost the diagnosis after X, and 50% of type B has lost the diagnosis after X.

Question: ***What is the most appropriate way to compare these rates?***

As an added note about the contingency table, there were those who developed new cases of either or both diagnoses only after having gone through X.